# Регулярное выражение (Только кирилица и латинские заглавные буквы и цифры и дефиз) а так же (латинские строчечные буквы и дефиз)

Tags: html, css, html5

Подскажите как сделать регулярные выражения для полей input 2 видов.

1. (Только кирилица и латинские заглавные буквы и цифры и дефиз)
2. (латинские строчечные буквы и дефиз)

Comment: Дефиз — это что такое?

Comment: поищите в просторах интернета, примеров очень много https://itwiki.dev/ru/front-end/html-reference/tags/input/pattern

Comment: @Эникейщик это соединительная черта между словами. Пример: вице-президент

Comment: @DarkSpace это называется "дефис".

Comment: @Эникейщик не заметил опечатку

Comment: Извеняюсь за опечатку, пишу в жутких условиях. Пока писал  упало 6 авиа бомб !!! Если я спросил значит трудно найти это решение ! Ссылку что дал  budaPest я того много видел но данного решения не нашел. Прошу помочь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы дефис учитывался не как спецсивол, его нужно указать последним.

1. [A-ZА-ЯЁ0-9-]*
2. [a-z-]*

Comment: Спасибо вам большое